# Make an android activity method thread safe

Tags: android

I have a method updateFoo() of an activity called both from a Handler thread every 5 seconds and from a button when user want to press it... updateFoo update the interface of my activity... to make this method thread safe I declared it "synchronized" ... Is that the right way???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well using a Handler : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html is thread safe. You can look at a tutorial here : http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/
I advice you to do long calculations in threads and the UI updates from the Handler (created in the main thread) call from your worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

Marking a method `synchronized` is a way to make it thread safe -- basically it makes it so that only one thread can be in the method at any given time.

However, that might not be the *best* option because if `updateFoo()` does some long running operations, your UI thread could hang (ie. the button press might get stuck waiting to get into [and execute] `updateFoo()`.

A more granular method would be to use locks, or some of Java's other threading options. If you post the code to your method, we'd be able to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for answers :) I tried this code, simpler than the project I'm building:

```
package provadroid.prova;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidSynch extends Activity {

    private TextView text_to_view;
    private Button change_text;


    private static final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.change_text = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.change_button);
        this.text_to_view = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.text_to_view);

        this.change_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                AndroidSynch.this.updateText(" Button ");
            }
        });

        doTheAutoRefresh(5000);

    }

    synchronized void updateText(String str)
    {
        this.text_to_view.setText(this.text_to_view.getText() + str);
    }

    void doTheAutoRefresh(long time) {
        handler.removeMessages(0);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                AndroidSynch.this.updateText(" Handler ");
                AndroidSynch.this.doTheAutoRefresh(5000);
            }

         }, time);
    }


}
```

A background handler runs in background every 5 seconds, after that update the textview.. The button updates the textview too...

All seems to be working well both with synchronized in update_text function and without it...I suppose that happens because update_text works on the UI so handler have an exclusive access and wait if someone is calling update_text..But if the function doesn't works on UI and is called by the handler and by a button or another handler, I should declare it synchronized, right??

Answer (score 0):

If you use message passing concurrency you should not need to worry too much about concurrency conflicts. To do this you would pass an immutable object to start the thread, the thread would not read or write to any shared memory outside of the thread, and the thread would then return an immutable object.

If you use shared memory communication, IMHO, simply declaring your method synchronized may or may not be enough to be thread safe. If the method IN TURN accesses shared memory that is not thread safe, atomic etc., there could be concurrency conflicts.